# IIS + Ajax UpdatePanel results in extreme memory usage

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

I have a update panel combined with gridview with sorting and paging.

I go into task manager to monitor the memory usage of the worker process (w3wp)

What I do is just click on the sort buttons rapidly.

With each click the memory of the process increases with about 2 mb

So I go from 30 mb memory usage to about 90. Then it stops at remains there, no memory is freed up. I am not using caching or session/application state.

What can be causing this, is there a setting in IIS to reduce the mem usage?

--

I also used .net profiler to examine my app memory usage: 4 mb, so what is the other 86 used for??? Even though it repots 4mb, in task manager it says 90 mb, so this leads me to believe that the rest is unamanaged memory which must be used by IIS in some way.

Comment: BTW this is not just an ajax issue. I tested this with other websites and the memory also goes up in the same fashion, just not so steeply. Let say 400 - 500 kb per request.

Comment: A made a test, no session state, no viewstate, no sql server, just an xml file a gridview and a updatepanel. Memory usage goes from 20 to 70 and doesnt go back down: http://rapidshare.com/files/433269321/ajaxtest.rar

Comment: plz someone test the project i posted, its an urgent issiue

Comment: This you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually with the GridView, and not the UpdatePanel. Its records are stored in your ViewState, so that's being passed back and forth every single postback. Also, as you click on the sort buttons rapidly, you're generating multiple requests to sort the data.  Depending on how you have your sort implemented, you could be duplicating the recordset for sorting with each click request.

There is no setting in IIS to "reduce memory usage" as it simply hosts your ASP.NET application.  Your application needs to address its own memory concerns.

**Sorting of a large amount of data can be a resource intensive process. I would say your best bet is to disable the sort button after it's been clicked and re-enable it once your data has been sorted.**

Comment: Used .net profiler to examine my app memory usage: 4 mb, so what is the other 86 used for???

Comment: The ViewState does not consume memory on the server. Unless you've got custom ViewState handling that moves the ViewState in memory you should not see increased constant memory consumption due to ViewState.

Comment: @diamandiev The GridView internally stores its data in the ViewState, unless you explicitly set it to not do so, but then you wouldn't be able to sort.

@Stilgar ViewState doesn't maintain memory on the server like Session does, but during a postback, the ViewState is sent back with the request.  In order to access the request's ViewState, it's stored in memory for the lifetime of the request.

Comment: It is but the question is about memory that lives for several requests.

Comment: Right, so if you have each request being bloated with GridView data in the ViewSource that's being passed back and forth, thus resulting in more memory being used for each request, and numerous requests, you'd have yourself a memory problem...

Comment: No you will not have any problem because the GC will kick in and free the memory. Usage of ViewState can increase the maximum amount of memory your app uses but cannot cause memory leaks.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that there were memory leaks...if my application consumes a large amount of memory, it could also be that my application has several objects and only a few orphaned ones (as opposed to memory leaks). As for GC, it's non-deterministic and targets orphaned objects in general.  In this person's case, submitting multiple sort requests that result in the processing of several ViewStates will keep the serialized objects in memory until the requests have been processed - thus preventing the GC from retrieving them until then.  All in all, refer to the bold portion of my post.

Comment: But really, I'm not trying to send diamandiev on a wild goose chase with ViewStates. I'm just saying they're contributing to the problem and that the GridView has some performance issues (partially due to the ViewState issue). I'm assuming that diamandiev is simply using the GridView's internal sorting feature so instead of arguing back and forth on ViewState impact, let's try and focus on something that's actually helpful - mainly how to reduce the amount of memory consumed as a result of his multi-clicking =)

Answer (score 0):

The .NET GC is non-deterministic. This means that it will run whenever it decides it should run. You can try calling GC.Collect() explicitly for example in the Page_Init event to see if the memory still increases but you have better remove it from the real app otherwise you are just preventing the GC from doing its work efficiently.

Comment: I did what you suggested and memory usage reduced by half. But why is the garbage collector not clearing the memory after the end of each request? –

Comment: Because the GC doesn't run constantly, only when it feels like it. But you can force a collection if you really want just like the post mentions.

Comment: Is making a module that handles the Application.EndRequest event and calls GC.Collect() a good idea?

Comment: No. You don't call GC.Collect! It is there for people who make frameworks like the socket API, database drivers and so on. They MAY SOMETIMES need it. I am too lazy to find the interview with Patrick Dussud (the main brain behind the .NET GC) where he explains it in more detail.